# Daily e-mail reminders with workflows

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, infopath, designer-workflow

I need a workflow which will check a custom list -for every row in this list- every day automatically and if the total value column is 0 then it will send an email to a user. Is it possible with SharePoint designer 2010 and InfoPath 2010? I can not use visual studio to develop a batch application.

Comment: Do you use 2013 workflow platform?

Answer (score 3):

If it's good enought to get a daily summary of new items where the total is 0, then you can create a view to show these and add an alert when new items enter the view.

Otherwise a timer job is the right solution or as you're not allowed to use VS against the server a program using the client object model which is run on a client PC by the task scheduler.

I'd only use the looping workflow described by @PirateEric as the last resort as it's a kludge which depending on the size of the list is going to put a heavy load your servers for no good reason.

Comment: A daily summry can solve my problem but I need to find all this items first. So maybe PirateEric's sugestion can solve my problem. I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

Realistically this screams timer job to me, but since you said you can't use Visual Studio, we'll have to resort to workflows.

There is a very detailed post on how to set up a for each type loop here, http://sharepointgypsy.blogspot.com/2011/11/create-for-each-loop-for-workflows.html. I recommend looking at that.

Comment: Thanks, PirateEric, maybe this can solve my problem but I think this will take long time. But I'll try it.