# SharePoint Designer Workflow based on %Column and after due date

Tags: sharepoint-designer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Daily e-mail reminders with workflows](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/36601/daily-e-mail-reminders-with-workflows)

I have two columns called "due date" and "percentage". Mail should trigger every day after due date, until percentage gets 100%. If it is not possible in designer can you provide me the code(VS 2010).

Comment: Look here _Daily e-mail reminders with workflows_: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/36601/daily-e-mail-reminders-with-workflows, so I vote for duplicate. And to your topic: I never got my daily workflow running. And you have 5 items per list only to be able to check with SPD.

Comment: Beside: Asking for entire code is not what people like to give at help.

Answer (score 0):

Please try first [Daily E-Mail-Reminder](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/36601/daily-e-mail-reminders-with-workflows) here at sp.stackexchange. To give you a visual help about two cycling workflows: [image: Two workflows to trigger each other in SPD 2010]taken from [how to configure a every day workflow](http://blog-sharepoint.blogspot.de/2010_01_01_archive.html)

As you see, it is quite complicated and in 2010 you have the limitation, that you can only cycle through 5 times. If you have more, your workflow stops with an error.